# passing a function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

Here is my event and as you can see I want to send a function with it as a parameter.

```
onclick="deleteItems('image', 'size', function(){GetImageSize();})"
```

The delete function is in a js file. In my js file I want to call my GetImageSize() function.

```
var deleteItems = function(module, controller, callback) {
   callback(); // ??????????    
}
```

I want to do this so I can rebuild my table when my ajax call has finished.

Hope you guys can help me

Regards Örvar

Comment: FYI, the asterisks (*) are not real code. It should work if you just remove them. Or you can do as stated below.

Comment: @Anthony: I removed the asterisks. I guess the OP just wanted to make them italics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the function, without calling it--just don't use the ending parens. The parens mean you're calling the function. In the case of passing the function into another function as a callback you want to leave the parens off. (And you don't need the anonymous function declaration around it.) It should read:

```
onclick="deleteItems('image', 'size', GetImageSize);"
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript functions are [first class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object). You could store functions in variables and pass them around as arguments to functions. Every function is actually a `Function` object.

Therefore, if you have a `GetImageSize()` function, you can simply pass it to the `deleteItems()` function just like any other variable:

```
deleteItems('image', 'size', GetImageSize);
```